# grep -ioP '(?<=Arguments=\")(.*)(?=":Language=)' in Bash scripting

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I was going through a bash script and read a line which says:

```
echo "Some line..." | grep -ioP '(?<=Arguments=\")(.*)(?=":Language=)'
```

I understood the grep part i.e `grep -ioP` but the input to grep i.e

`'(?<=Arguments=\")(.*)(?=":Language=)'` type of expression is encountered for the first time.

What does it mean? Does it mean something special to grep or it's just the grepping of similar string from the echo string part?

Thanks!

Comment: If you encounter a regex you don"t understand, sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) usually do a great job explaining them

Comment: That is a cool site, thanks!

Comment: Your tags should include `grep`, you are not using `bash` here for the regular expressions, only for the `echo`.

Comment: @cdarke, I added the tag but it was removed. See the edits.

Answer (score 0):

These are *look-around assertions*. `(?<...)` is a *look-behind* (what precedes) and `(?=...)` is a *look-forward* (what follows). The reason for them is they aren't part of the match, so `-o` won't output them.